# How to run a two-way ANOVA with a random variable followed by pairwise comparisons?

Tags: r, anova, multiple-comparisons, random-effects-model

I have a dataset with which I would like to compare the effect of species and habitat on movement rate, with pairwise comparisons. I would also like to include the effect of individual  (as a random factor?) - this random factor is the part I don't know how to do, at least not in the framework of `Anova()`.

Here's a subset of the data:

```
species  <- c("a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "b", "c", 
              "a", "a", "b", "c", "a")
habitat  <- c("x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "x", "x", "y", "z", "y", "y", "z", "z", "x", 
              "x", "y", "y", "z", "z")
mvt.rate <- c(6, 5, 7, 8, 9, 4, 3, 5, 6, 9, 3, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8)
ind      <- as.factor(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4))
data1    <- data.frame(species, habitat, mvt.rate, ind)
```

Currently, I'm simply running a two-way ANOVA with pairwise comparisons, without considering the effect of individual, like so:

```
fit <- lm(mvt.rate ~ habitat + species, data=data1)
require(car)
Anova(fit, type="III")
require(agricolae)
    #pairwise comparison of habitats
comparison.hab <- HSD.test(fit, "habitat", group=TRUE)                     
    #pairwise comparison of species
comparison.sp <- HSD.test(fit, "species", group=TRUE)
```

In the dataset, each row represents a movement, and in many cases, individuals make several (non-independent) movements - I am currently not considering this non-independence of mvt.rate and individual.  I believe the correct way to do this is to consider individual as a random variable, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: You forgot to include the values of `homerange` in your question.

Comment: @Luke I edited the example slightly as it contained an error. Feel free to revert it.

Comment: Some individuals are belonging to more than one species. Does this make any sense? (I don't think so.) If you can clarify that, I post another answer in addition to AlefSin's nice answer.

Comment: You're right Henrik - I didn't think of that when putting together this mock dataset - individuals should only be one species!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can show you how to model the individuals as a random effect. You can simply use use the `lme` function from the `nlme` package. The syntax will be very similar to `lm`:

```
require(nlme)
fit<-lme(mvt.rate ~ habitat +species, random=~1|ind, data=data1)
```

As for the pairwise comparisons, for `lme` you can use the `glht` function:

```
require(multcomp)
summary(glht(fit,  linfct=mcp(habitat = "Tukey")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the variability that is related with individuals: `pre.fit=lm(mvt.rate ~ind,data=data1)` and then `fit<-lm(pre.fit$residuals ~ data1$habitat +data1$species)`